# How to send data between two different port on one application

Tags: javascript, express

I'm using expressjs library. It works on localhost:8000 as a server and i'm showing static pages with it. My application works on localhost:4200. I tried to use same cookie or localStorage on different pages of ports but it didn't work. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by calling the routes on localhost:8000 in your main application only, and since it is working on two different ports you may run to error due to Cors policy and for that you may look up to these answers. [cors enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

When you're working on different ports, if the cookies have the 'SameSite' attribute set to 'Host Only' and the domain set to 'localhost', they will be visible/accessible from both domains regardless of the port number.

As @codingmaster says, if it's different domains, you will have to implement cors management for different domains..

But since you own both applications, during production, one can be on the main domain while the other on a subdomain, then you'll have to set the **domain** attribute of the cookie to your domain, e.g: `example.com` and the **SameSite** attribute can remain `HostOnly` and the cookies will be accessible

Comment: This will not work in production well though, as I assume they will be actual domains. You can use 3rd-party cookies, but some people have them blocked (some browsers by default).

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are trying to do here is have the cookie/local storage shared between two locations.

1. Do you need 2 locations? I'm pretty sure you can serve your app on the same express server.
2. If you are using the express one for backend (not frontend), you can pass the required information within your requests, with POST, GET, PATCH, etc. Have a google for more info on sending info between a client and server.
3. If both are frontend, maybe try to not have it that way. If it's necessary, you can use what I mentioned above to send info between the servers.

Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: 1. I tried to run on localhost:4200 both of but it didnt work. One of it Angular project , other one is static pages with expressjs so i cant share data between them.
2.I'm using express for frontend.
3.Ok i will try it! Thank you.

Comment: If it works, please consider marking my answer as correct 